# Python2 command not found

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, python-2.x, git-bash

So I tried cloning this git just like the tutorial did and the program is made on python2 and as the tutorial said I was gonna run the command `python2 main.py` but then it doesn't work, what can I do to make it work? please help me, thank you.

OS: Windows 10
Python Version: Python 3.8
Command ran: python2 main.py
Ran on: Git Bash
more info: I also can't run the command:`python3` on Bash so I use `winpty python.exe` instead and I don't have python 2 installed, only python 3.8 would that be the cause?

please help me out thank you :)

Comment: if you have python3.8 installed, then you'd be running ```python3 main.py```

Comment: @ewong the OP says that he is running the python2 code, maybe there will necessity to change some code - like `print` statements

Comment: @spiridon_the_sun_rotator, true.  So if the OP needs python2, then python2 needs to be installed.  Otherwise, as you mentioned, the code needs to be tweaked.

Comment: will it be okay if i have python 3 and 2 installed? i use ```winpty python.exe``` afterall and not python3

Answer (score 6):

Running python 2 scripts using python 3 may give errors.

> I don't have python 2 installed

[Download Python 2 here](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/)

You can have both python 2 and python 3 installed on windows at same time. But make sure your environment variables are properly configured for both.

After installing python 2,
Goto installation directory (default location is `C:/python27/`) and make a copy of `python.exe` and rename it as `python2.exe`.
After, add python2 directory to `PATH` environment variable then you can run python 2 scripts like `python2 script.py` on your commandline.

[How to change environment variable in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10)

Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

you have to find out where you have installed python2, if there is any.

```
which python
which python2
```

In all likelihood, it is just simply python

```
python --version
```

if you get 2.x, you can use **python** command to run the python code.